# Bad allocator implementation

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11

I've got a pretty simple problem. I've been whipping up a non-thread-safe allocator. The allocator is a fairly simple memory arena strategy- allocate a big chunk, put all allocations in it, do nothing for deallocation, remove the whole lot on arena destruction. However, actually attempting to *use* this scheme throws an access violation.

```
static const int MaxMemorySize = 80000;
template <typename T>
class LocalAllocator
{
  public:
      std::vector<char>* memory;
      int* CurrentUsed;
      typedef T value_type;
      typedef value_type * pointer;
      typedef const value_type * const_pointer;
      typedef value_type & reference;
      typedef const value_type & const_reference;
      typedef std::size_t size_type;
      typedef std::size_t difference_type;

    template <typename U> struct rebind { typedef LocalAllocator<U> other; };

    template <typename U>
    LocalAllocator(const LocalAllocator<U>& other) {
        CurrentUsed = other.CurrentUsed;
        memory = other.memory;
    }
    LocalAllocator(std::vector<char>* ptr, int* used) {
        CurrentUsed = used;
        memory = ptr;
    }
    template<typename U> LocalAllocator(LocalAllocator<U>&& other) {
        CurrentUsed = other.CurrentUsed;
        memory = other.memory;
    }
    pointer address(reference r) { return &r; }
    const_pointer address(const_reference s) { return &r; }
    size_type max_size() const { return MaxMemorySize; }
    void construct(pointer ptr, value_type&& t) { new (ptr) T(std::move(t)); }
    void construct(pointer ptr, const value_type & t) { new (ptr) T(t); }
    void destroy(pointer ptr) { static_cast<T*>(ptr)->~T(); }

    bool operator==(const LocalAllocator& other) const { return Memory == other.Memory; }
    bool operator!=(const LocalAllocator&) const { return false; }

    pointer allocate(size_type n) {
        if (*CurrentUsed + (n * sizeof(T)) > MaxMemorySize)
            throw std::bad_alloc();
        auto val = &(*memory)[*CurrentUsed];
        *CurrentUsed += (n * sizeof(T));
        return reinterpret_cast<pointer>(val);
    }
    pointer allocate(size_type n, pointer) {
        return allocate(n);
    }
    void deallocate(pointer ptr, size_type n) {}

    pointer allocate() {
        return allocate(sizeof(T));
    }
    void deallocate(pointer ptr) {}
};
```

I've initialized `memory` to point to a vector which is resized to the MaxMemorySize, and I've also initialized CurrentUsed to point to an int which is zero. I fed in an allocator with these values to the constructor of a `std::unordered_map`, but it keeps throwing an access violation in the STL internals. Any suggestions?

Edit: Here's my usage:

```
std::vector<char> memory;
int CurrentUsed = 0;
memory.resize(80000);
std::unordered_map<int, int, std::hash<int>, std::equal_to<int>, LocalAllocator<std::pair<const int, int>>> dict(
    std::unordered_map<int, int>().bucket_count(),
    std::hash<int>(),
    std::equal_to<int>(),
    LocalAllocator<std::pair<const int, int>>(&memory, &CurrentUsed)
);
// start timer
QueryPerformanceCounter(&t1);

for (int i=0;i<10000;i++)
    dict[i]=i; // crash
```

Edit: Bloody hell. It worked when I increased the size to 1MB. I had to increase it to over 800,000 bytes to get it to work without throwing.

Comment: Is this one of these new stateful allocators? Where is that documented?

Comment: It's entirely possible that STL implementations haven't really implemented stateful allocators yet. Also, what STL implementation are you using, and what errors are you getting? How do you use it in a `std::unordered_map`?

Comment: How are you testing this code?  trivial usage of it on an unordered_map with vc2010 works just fine for me.

Comment: It works for me (GCC 4.6.1) after fixing the typos and removing the line `construct(pointer, value_type&&)`.

Comment: `allocate()` must provide correct alignment, as it is now, allocations are not aligned.

Comment: It's documented because the methods are not static and the code compiles. @Nicol: Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 2):

When I test this code, the `rebind` is being used to request multiple allocators against the same memory block.  I put

```
cout << n << " " << sizeof(T) << " " << typeid(T).name() << endl;
```

at the top of allocate(size_type) and when I added three elements to a `unordered_map` got:

```
1 64 struct std::_List_nod<...>
16 4 struct std::_List_iterator<...>
1 64 struct std::_List_nod<...>
1 64 struct std::_List_nod<...>
1 64 struct std::_List_nod<...>
```

If your implementation isn't coincidentally using nice round 64-byte requests this class will return mis-aligned allocations.

Comment: So you are.  I was doing the order of operations wrong.  Replacing answer with a new theory.

Comment: Misaligned access is not an error on x64- and I added code to check and fix the alignment with no effect.

Answer (score 0):

MSVC10's hashtable types just has a ton of space overhead for small value types.  It's overrunning the amount of space you've reserved and throwing bad_alloc.

It's implemented as a `list<value_t>` holding all the elements and a hash bucket `vector<list<value_t>::iterator>` with between 2 and 16 slots per element.

That's a total of 4 to 18 pointers of overhead per element.

Something like this implementation is probably required by the standard.  Unlike vector, unordered_map has a requirement that elements not be moved once added to the container.